# MatTableDataSource : cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im getting following error while using angular material data table. i am able to get the data from api but cannot render it in view.

**Error:**

[error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjT7x.jpg)

**TS:**

```
      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();  
      displayedColumns: string[] = ["Part#", "Description"];      
      getSearchResult() {
         let params = {
             ParentCategoryID: 0,
             CategoryID: 0,
             ManufacturerID: 0,  
       };
        this._httpService.getSearchResult(params).subscribe((resp: any) => {
        this.searchResult = resp;
        this.dataSource.data = this.searchResult;                 
       });
    }
```

**View:**

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8"> 
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Part#">
           <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Part# </th>
           <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element "> {{element.PartCode}}            
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element "> 
              {{element.DiagramDescription}} </td>
         </ng-container>    

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: where you are accessing getSearchResult().? on constructor or on ngOnInit()

Comment: inside ngOnInit()

Comment: Is your service return response...Have you checked.?

Comment: yes..its returning the response correctly

Comment: here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scbbxj?file=app/table-basic-example.ts try to comapre your code with this.

Comment: can you post some piece of service response here

Answer (score 14):

Try putting `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();` inside the Constructor:

```
constructor() {
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**make initialisation inside constructor**

```
this.dataSource.data = [];
```

**OR**

**add the subscribe code inside constructor**

```
constructor(private _httpService: imported service name) {this._httpService.getSearchResult(params).subscribe((resp: any) => {
    this.searchResult = resp;
    this.dataSource.data = this.searchResult;                 
   });}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code:

`this.dataSource= new MatTableDataSource(this.searchResult);`

Comment: by using the above the error is gone but the data is not rendered in view..Do i need to change anything in view as well ???

Comment: i got a property name wrong ..thats y its not rendered in view..its working fine now..but paginator is not working ?? any reason??

Comment: Yes. You need to declare
@ViewChild(MatPaginator)
  paginator: MatPaginator;

Then write     this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

Comment: Hi Asridh,If solution help you. Please like.

Answer (score 2):

Your dataSource is not initialized yet.
When you initialized your dataSource, you can do something like this :

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource = [];
```

OR

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The error occur because the table is not already initialized when you try to access to the data.
Usually occurs also when you try to render the rows before the table is initialized.
To solve it try to run

This should solve the problem:

**TS:**

```
dataSource = any[];  
displayedColumns: string[] = ["Part#", "Description"];      
getSearchResult() {
   let params = {
      ParentCategoryID: 0,
      CategoryID: 0,
      ManufacturerID: 0,  
   };
   this._httpService.getSearchResult(params).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.searchResult = resp;
      this.dataSource = this.searchResult;                 
   });
}
```

At least try to put the code after the view is initialized in ngAfterContentInit.